# Can't access certain tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the product images from the product pages of Amazon.in and am running the returned html through bs4. When I view the html in the Firefox developer console I'm able to see all the images embedded within separate `<li>` tags with only one being visible at a time.

Any image besides the main landing image becomes visible after you hover over its thumbnail on the left of the main image. When I try to retrieve he contents of these `<li>` tags using bs4 I use the `find_all()` method to retrieve all the appropriate tags containing images.

However, when I do this. I'm only able to retrieve the landing image that is initially displayed and none of the other image containing `<li>` tags are in the output. I can't figure out why since these tags are all present in the HTML when I view it in the browser's console. Am I going to have to resort to a headless browser implementation?

Comment: It seems that the content you´re trying to scrape is loaded/rendered in your browser. If you don't see it in the raw HTML / source but only in the dev console then yes – you need a headless browser like Selenium.

Comment: Can you share the URL and what have you tried so far?

Comment: A URL would be handy, it may be loaded in the browser in which case you may be able to sniff out an API or at the very least hit it with Selenium.